# Folder Encryption Software

Tags: backup, encryption, cloud-service, cloud-storage

I am using Google Drive locally on my PC as an off-site backup solution for my data. To ensure there are levels of encryption to help prevent my files being readable, I am using the following method:

1. Using [Symantec PGP Disk Encryption](https://www.symantec.com/products/information-protection/encryption/endpoint-encryption) I assign two partitions (`F:` and `G:`) to the system manually
2. Using [CryptSync](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CryptSync.html) I make a pair between `F:` and `G:` and encrypt with a password
3. Using [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=15155) I copy from `D:\Documents` (where the PGP disks are stored) to Google Drive

Now, I like using Symantec PGP as it encrypts all my files into a container, and prevents anyone accessing them without a password.

As for CryptSync, the issue I found is there is no hierarchy to follow. If I made a pair between `F:` to `G:` and then `D:\Documents` to `C:\Users\Michael Nancarrow\Google Drive` it would attempt to copy both at once and just corrupt data.

I've set the PGP disks to stay alive for 120 minutes, and set CryptSync to check every 60 minutes - all I need to do is manually start both applications (I know I could add them both to startup, but that defeats the purpose of trying to ensure my data is not accessed, to an extent).

My problem is I now need to rely on a third tool (SyncToy) to copy the actual PGP disks into another directory - the third directory is my "backup drive" that I want to use for data integrity. I know I could make a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)/[junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) (or even use `robocopy`) but it lacks features.

To summarize I want *a single tool* that can:

- Copy data from `Folder A` to `Folder B` with encryption (CryptSync uses 7Z's AES-256)
- Based on completion of `Folder B`, copy `Folder A` and `Folder B` to `Folder C`

It must run on Windows 8, but can be a paid solution.

Comment: If you are not married to Google Drive, look into [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/). Its client encrypts files locally on your PC before uploading & decrypts on download. The SpiderOak team don't have any access to your encryption keys, and couldn't even help you if you forgot your passphrase. I have been happily using to for many years. It also has apps for Android and iOs.

Comment: @mawg Want to make it an answer?

Comment: Done. Did you go for it, then?

Comment: @Mawg Yes, this was implemented for the project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not married to Google Drive, look into [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com).

Its client encrypts files locally on your PC before uploading & decrypts on download.

The SpiderOak team don't have any access to your encryption keys, and couldn't even help you if you forgot your passphrase.

I have been happily using to for many years. It also has apps for Android and iOs.

150 GB Plan
$5
Per Month
or $59 annually

400 GB Plan
$9
Per Month
or $99 annually

2 TB Plan
$12
Per Month
or $129 annually

5 TB
$25
Per Month
or $279 annually

all with unlimited devices, see https://spideroak.com/one/

Answer (score -2):

AJC Sync lets you backup to GoogleDrive and will encrypt your files during the process so they arrive on the cloud storage already encrypted.  This way you can have your local files un-encrypted and sync them against the encrypted ones on GoogleDrive.  You can also encrypt all of the folder and file names.  You can run it manually and see exactly what will happen to your files each time or on a schedule.  It also has built in diff so you can see how files have changed etc.
See [AJC Sync](http://www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm)

Also the support for this software is very responsive so you can ask questions and get help with your solution.